# XCode autolayout not working properly on devices other than selected in 'View as'

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder, xcode9

I am facing an issue with XCode 9 Interface Builder.

When I try to test my application on hardware device (iPhone 6s) and I set *"View as: iPhone 8"* everything works like a charm (screenshot #1 below), but when I change device to *iPhone 5* it looks like XCode passes wrong coordinates to my phone (screenshot #2 below).

It happens only in my biggest project and I have completely no idea why. Autolayout is set properly, there is no "bad constraint" or even a warning.

Could some kind person answer me - why is this occurring and how can this be fixed? Could it possibly be some option in XCode?

### Screenshots:

- Not proper

[image]

- Proper

[image]

Comment: so where are your autolayouts?

Comment: What do you mean, Sir? 
I set it like I always do, but I am only facing problems in this one project. Everything works well if hardware device is same as selected in _View as_, so it looks like some kind of XCode bug.

Comment: Maybe you did it like always but you were always doing it wrong, how do we know if you didn't show us anything?

Comment: You're right. I've added every single constraint in IB, here is the screenshot:
https://imgur.com/mVq55vO

Comment: every square (add funds, cash out...) is in a stack view? how are they set there?

Comment: Thank you for being interested.
Yes, they are in stack view, here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/2Np3A

Here is the code setting theme for them: https://pastebin.com/ZsN3a3Vy

Comment: So height is calculating wrong, when do you call setTheme() ?

Comment: In overridden _viewDidLoad()_ method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your `setTheme()` function in `viewWillAppear()` code did not have correct height to set label in good position. View is still not loaded so frames are wrong

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been trying to call my _setTheme()_ method in _viewWillAppear()_, but (unfortunately) it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: why don't you set it via constraints in storyboard?

Comment: It doesn't really matter.
I can add simple view with all _centerX, centerY, width, height_ constraints in the center of _UIViewController_ and problem still shows up. That's why I suspect something in XCode options rather than error in my constraints.

Comment: so simply clearing all data should help, shift + alt + cmd + k

Comment: Calling my setupTheme() method inside viewWillAppear() solved my problem. Thank you, Lu_!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check autolayout constraints and code to match different screen sizes. For example, corner radius of the upper circle is constant and should be variable depending on containing view width, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is already done this way, so unfortunately my problem is still not solved.

Comment: Corner radius of the upper circle is not constant and looks exactly like this:
_circleViewGradient.layer.cornerRadius = circleViewGradient.frame.width / 2;_